# Clicking a Checkbox in an Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to simulate a click on a material-ui checkbox.  I have tried

`selectAllCheckbox.simulate("change", { target: { checked: true } });`

and

```
act(() => {
  selectAllCheckbox.props().onClick();
});
```

I have tried re-finding the item and updating the wrapper, and I cannot get the checked prop to change.

I feel like I missing something fundamental.

I have a codesandbox here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/enzymetestformaterialuitable-t1ruq
the sandbox has a material-ui table (lifted from their demos page).

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I got a hand from a few sources including https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/216

complete sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/enzymetestformaterialuitable-updb9 with tests passing

check the 4th checkbox on the table:

```
 let innerInputElement5 = wrapper
   .find('[role="checkbox"]')
   .hostNodes()
   .at(4);
 innerInputElement5.simulate("click");
```

check the indeterminate checkbox in the header:

```
let selectAllCheckboxInHeader = wrapper
      .find(TableHead)
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .simulate("change", { target: { checked: true } });
```